# Web Crawler With Python

Tags: python, web-applications, web-crawler

thank you for taking an interest in my question. I'm currently studying Computer Science in university, and I believe that I have a pretty good grasp of Python programming. With that in mind, and now that I'm learning full-stack development, I wanted to develop a web crawler in Python (since I hear that it's good at that) to skim through sites like Manta and Tradesi looking for small businesses without websites so that I can get in touch with their owners and do some pro-bono work to kickstart my career as a web developer. Problem is, I have never made a web crawler before, in any language, so I thought that the helpful folk at Stack Overflow could give me some insight about web crawlers, particularly how I should go about learning how to make them, and ideas on how to implement it for those particular websites.

Any input is appreciated. Thank you, and have a good day/evening!

Comment: First of all, you should read about existing web-crawlers and how they work. Then give a shot at writing one, or using one! If you have any more specific question from there, StackOverflow will be a good ressource, but at the moment your question is not really a question.

Comment: I see, that totally makes sense! Thank you for your advice :)

Comment: You may use BeautifulSoup4 for this purpose, it's fairly easy to understand, the full docs are here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to loop through an array of URLs and import data from each.

```
import urllib 
import re 
import json
dateslist = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/dates/dates.txt").read() dateslistlist = thedates.split("\n")
for thedate in dateslist: 
    myfile = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/dates/" + thedate +".txt", "w+") 
    myfile.close()

    htmltext = urllib.urlopen("http://www.hockey-reference.com/friv/dailyleaders.cgi?month=" + themonth + "& day=" theday "& year=" theyear "")
    data = json.load(htmltext)
    datapoints = data["data_values"]

    myfile = open("C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/dates/" + thedate +".txt", "a")
    for point in datapoints:
            myfile.write(str(symbol+","+str(point[0])+","+str(point[1])+"\n"))
    myfile.close()
```

#

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.privredni-imenik.com/pretraga?abcd=&keyword=&cities_id=0&category_id=0&sub_category_id=0&page=1"
current_page = 1

while current_page < 200:
    print(current_page)
    url = base_url + str(current_page)
    #current_page += 1
    r = requests.get(url)
    zute_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    firme = zute_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'jobs-item'})

    for title in firme:
        title1 = title.findAll('h6')[0].text
        print(title1)
        adresa = title.findAll('div', {'class': 'description'})[0].text
        print(adresa)
        kontakt = title.findAll('div', {'class': 'description'})[1].text
        print(kontakt)
        print('\n')
        page_line = "{title1}\n{adresa}\n{kontakt}".format(
            title1=title1,
            adresa=adresa,
            kontakt=kontakt
        )
    current_page += 1
```

Keep in mind, there are many, many, many ways to do this kind of thing, and each site is different from all others, so the final result you come up with will be highly customized and very specific in it's intended use.